# How to disable a p:commandLink onclick and enable it oncomplete?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

A `<p:commandButton>` can be disabled `onclick` and enabled `oncomplete` with the help of the `widgetVar` property associated with it as follows.

```
<p:commandButton widgetVar="widget"
                 onclick="PF('widget').disable()"
                 oncomplete="PF('widget').enable()"
                 value="Submit"
                 process="@this"
                 actionListener="#{bean.action}"/>
```

What about a `<p:commandLink>`? There is no `widgetVar` property associated with a `<p:commandLink>`. Is there any shortcut?

Answer (score 3):

You are right, commandLink doesn't have any widget object, but it's a normal link after all, you can achieve this by `jQuery` and `CSS`:

*CSS*

```
a.disabled {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
   color: gray;
}
```

*xhtml*

```
<p:commandLink id="ajaxSubmit" 
               value="Submit" 
               onclick="$('#ajaxSubmit').addClass('disabled')"
               oncomplete="$('#ajaxSubmit').removeClass('disabled')">
</p:commandLink>
```

---

Note: the jQuery selector might vary, but mostly would be `$('#formId\\:ajaxSubmit')`

Comment: Are you sure this works? Unfortunately, I found no effect after doing this. I used a correct jQuery selector looking into the generated HTML code - `$('#formId\\:linkId')` as you also stated.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with basic javascript.

1. Give the command link an id

   ```
   <p:commandLink id="theLink"/>
   ```
2. Set the `disabled` attribute via javascript

   ```
   <script>

       function toggleLink(currentStatus){

            document.getElementById("theLink").disabled=currentStatus;
       }

   </script>
   ```
3. Use the rudimentary script on the commandLink

   ```
   <p:commandLink id="theLink" onclick="toggleLink(true);" oncomplete="toggleLink(false);"/>
   ```

EDIT: For use within a datatable, you should be able to inline the function in the `onclick`

```
     <p:commandLink id="theLink" onclick="this.disabled=true;" oncomplete="this.disabled=false;""/>
```

Comment: This should work though I did not try it yet but referring to an element which is inside an iterating component like `<p:dataTable>` by its `id` does not seem possible. `<p:commandLink>` is nested inside a `<p:dataGrid>` which in turn contains several other components like `<p:carousel>`. The `id` of `<p:commandLink>` in the generated HTML would be like `formId:dataGridId:0:linkId`. It is a dynamic `id`. Can this be referenced by a JavaScript/jQuery function in this way?

Comment: @Tiny - You failed to indicate in your question that the commandLink is contained in a table

Comment: The last update did not work. `<p:commandLink process="@this" onclick="this.disabled=true;" oncomplete="this.disabled=false;" value="Submit"/>`, even though the link was not wrapped in a table. The link is never seen disabled. No error on the browser console.